# How to Add SDL Media Manager to the Slide-out Navigation?

Tags: 2013, gui-extensions, media-manager

The [SDL slide-out navigation pane](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8BAC5B1A-98B8-4F63-848F-285124F3B175) lets us view multiple SDL applications from the same panel (via the slide out "hamburger" menu).

I see how we can [extend the slide-out navigation Welcome screen](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-ACCFC238-87AB-4C1E-8505-E84F38E1550C) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) and a recent SmartTarget update shows `Targeting` in the slide-out Navigation in our environment.

Where can I find instructions to show SDL Media Manager for a given SDL Tridion setup?

**Edit**:

Following John's example, I was able to set the following working example for external URLs (example with SDL Live Content).

**Notes**:

- Attribute `domain` starts with `http://`
- Attribute `url` starts with `/`
- I matched `domainId` to the `applicationDomain` node with the matching `id` attribute
- Sites that restrict being embedded in iFrames throw an error in the console (`Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.`).

```
  <applicationEntryPointGroups>
    <applicationEntryPointGroup id="docs" title="Documentation">
      <applicationEntryPoints>
        <applicationEntryPoint id="SDL Live Content" type="docs" domainId="docs" url="/" />
      </applicationEntryPoints>
    </applicationEntryPointGroup>
    <applicationEntryPointGroup id="wcm.cm" title="Web Content Management">
      ...
    </applicationEntryPointGroup >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i recently wrote a blog post about how to do this, you can find it here : http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/adding-content-to-the-side-panel-navigation-using-anguilla-framework

I did try the info provided in your links but i couldn't get it to work, i also noticed that that the 'targeting' link is also included using the method described in my blog post.

hope this helps.

thanks

john

Comment: Nice! How did I miss your post? I added notes on how I made an  "external" link work. Thanks! +1 and I'll accept soon if there are no other answers.

Comment: WTF just accept it immediately alvin :) - glad to help and thanks for the notes

Comment: Now accepted. I had to give others a chance. :-)