# How to add custom links on top Header & Left Menu

Tags: content-manager, javascript, sites-9.6

As per requirement, we need to Add custom links on CMS Top header & Left Navigation. can you please help me which files can be updated for reflecting these links. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Presuming "Custom Links" is intended to represent some sort of GUI Extension... I would recommend you read around and try something from `GUI Extensions` and `AddOn Service` . You may also want to confirm if the requirement is explicit to the old UI or to include the new UI - for which I don't believe GUI extensions are fully supported (but you should check on that)

Comment: no, they are not supported for the new UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add some info on custom pages and the slide out navigation.

### Custom pages

For shortcuts to other applications, consider using the built-in **Custom Pages** feature for adding custom (iFramed) pages.

As an administrator, add them in the shortcuts section of the Classic UI Content Manager Explorer. Here's an older [video of the steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP2_nODxwPo), otherwise [refer to the documentation](https://docs.rws.com/956379/100454/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/adding-or-editing-a-custom-page).

### Slide out navigation - custom welcome area

Otherwise, the links in the [left slide out navigation can be extended with custom areas and code](https://docs.rws.com/816112/129880/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/creating-a-custom-area-in-the-slide-out-navigation-welcome-screen) per the documentation.

This is an example to add a custom welcome area to the slide out navigation.

```xml
<ext:add>
    <ext:extension name="CustomWelcomeAreaName" assignid="CustomWelcomeAreaID">
        <ext:control>CustomWelcomeAreaImpl.ascx</ext:control>
        <ext:pagetype></ext:pagetype>
        <ext:renderinblock>false</ext:renderinblock>
        <ext:apply>
            <ext:view name="Welcome">
            <ext:control id="SidePanelExtendableArea" />
            </ext:view>
        </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
</ext:add>
```

### Slide out navigation - application entry points

Depending on your version, you may also be able to extend the slide out navigation by adding "application entry points" to the `manifests.xml` configuration file. Here's [an example on Tridion Stack Exchange](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7333/how-to-add-sdl-media-manager-to-the-slide-out-navigation) based on [John Winter's blog post](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/adding-content-to-the-side-panel-navigation-using-anguilla-framework).

```xml
<applicationSuite id="wcm" authenticationUrl="/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Authentication/Authentication.aspx" authenticationMode="on-access">
  <applicationDomains>
    <applicationDomain id="local" domain="" />
    <applicationDomain id="docs" domain="http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/" />
  </applicationDomains> 

  <applicationEntryPointGroups>
    <applicationEntryPointGroup id="docs" title="Documentation">
      <applicationEntryPoints>
        <applicationEntryPoint id="SDL Live Content" type="docs" domainId="docs" url="/" />
      </applicationEntryPoints>
    </applicationEntryPointGroup>
    <applicationEntryPointGroup id="wcm.cm" title="Web Content Management">

    </applicationEntryPointGroup >
```

### Custom URLs?

Finally, if the shortcuts are related to specific content types (or Schemas) in Tridion Sites, consider custom URLs, which give editors field-specific pop-up windows as a sort of content entry customization or custom help text. See [this post on Custom URLs](https://www.createandbreak.net/2011/12/sdl-tridion-custom-help.html) in case these might be a good fit for your use case.

Answer (score 4):

oh boy, explaining gui extension requires a lot of time, i suggest you take a look at how they are created using this page in documentation:

https://docs.rws.com/816112/696275/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/gui-extensions

For adding new button in ribbon bar, you can look at the following page:

https://docs.rws.com/816112/745101/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/adding-a-new-button-to-a-group-in-a-ribbon-toolbar

Basically, you need something like this in your editors config:

```
<ext:ribbontoolbars>
          <ext:add>
            <ext:extension pageid="HomePage" groupid="ext_group" name="group" assignid="cm_group_Big" >
              <ext:command>MyCommand</ext:command>
              <ext:title>Do something</ext:title>
              <ext:dependencies>
                <cfg:dependency>MyConfig.ConfigSet</cfg:dependency>
              </ext:dependencies>
              <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="DashboardView">
                  <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar"/>
                </ext:view>
              </ext:apply>
            </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
        </ext:ribbontoolbars>
```

You can also download some of the open-source GUI extensions (Some written for alchemy store) and see how they are implemented. I also know that Robert Curlete had a lot of tutorials on this topic. You can google it.